# Disabling http in Wildfly 10?

Tags: spring-mvc, java-8, wildfly-10

I have added one header in my response header to provide security in my site but when am adding this header at landing page this header opening my website with `http protocol`.

```
 http:/www.xyz.com
```

I would like to open my landing page with `https` i.e

```
https:/www.xyz.com
```

The header which I have added is `Strict-Transport-Security` and `Strict-Transport-Security` header must not be sent over an unencrypted channel.
So can you please suggest me how to disable `http` in my landing page other than this I am able to access my whole website with `https`

```
 <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:3.0">
        <buffer-cache name="default"/>
        <server name="default-server">
            <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https" disallowed-methods="TRACE TRACK"/>
            <https-listener name="https" enabled-protocols="TLSv1.2" lve-peer-address="true" socket-binding="https" disallowed-methods="TRACE TRACK"/>
            <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
            <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>            
            <filter-ref name="content-security-policy-header"/>
            <filter-ref name="strict-transport-security-header"/>
            <filter-ref name="public-key-pins-header"/>                    
            </host>
        </server>          
        <handlers>
            <file name="welcome-content" path="${jboss.home.dir}/welcome-content"/>
        </handlers>
     <filters>               
        <response-header name="strict-transport-security-header" header-name="Strict-Transport-Security" header-value="max-age=31622400; includeSubDomains"/>
        <response-header name="public-key-pins-header" header-name="Public-Key-Pins" header-value="pin-sha256=&quot;abc=&quot;;pin-sha256=&quot;Xyz=&quot;;  pin-sha256=&quot;h6801m+wer=&quot;; pin-sha256=&quot;/BUJ=&quot;; includeSubDomains ; max-age=2592000 "/>
    </filters>
 </subsystem>
```

Please help me to resolve this issue I want to open my website landing page with `https protocol`.

Thanks.